# How do I make a format with beamer preloaded

Tags: beamer, pdftex, initex

Loading beamer is slow, even on a fast processor, so I was wondering if I could make format with beamer preloaded. Now it's been decades since I last ran `initex` but I thought:

1. run `initex`
2. `input lplain`
3. eh, maybe `documentclass{beamer}`
4. `\dump`

but my texlive installation doesn't even have `lplain.tex`

Pdflatex says `preloaded format=pdflatex` so I tried

```
initex
This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2022/MacPorts 2022.62882_3) (INITEX)
**&pdflatex
```

and then maybe input beamer and dump, but this immediately runs to

```
No pages of output.
Transcript written on pdflatex.log.
mktexfmt [INFO]: log file copied to: /Users/eijkhout/.texlive2022/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.log
mktexfmt [INFO]: /Users/eijkhout/.texlive2022/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt installed.
mktexfmt [INFO]: disabled formats: 5
mktexfmt [INFO]: successfully rebuilt formats: 1
mktexfmt [INFO]: not selected formats: 55
mktexfmt [INFO]: total formats: 61
mktexfmt [INFO]: exiting with status 0
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

So, eh, I'm stymied too. Do TeX installations these days still come with enough tools to dump new formats?

Comment: lplain hasn't been used since 1993:-)  see https://ctan.org/pkg/mylatex?lang=en

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That puts a lower bound of 3 decades on how long it's been since I've build formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `beamer10.tex` is

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

```
pdftex --ini \&pdflatex mylatex.ltx beamer10.tex
```

produces  `mylatex.fmt`

```
pdftex \&mylatex beamer-doc
```

will process documents with the format.

You might need `&` rather than `\&` depending on your shell

Comment: Ok, got it. The document still needs documentclass, and begin/end document.

Comment: And I appreciate the work you put in this, but I guess my setup is a little complicated for it. For instance, I load the `morewrites` style, but despite that, on the actual document I get `! Bad number (23).
\ReadBookmarks ...mmediate \openout \@outlinefile`

Comment: @VictorEijkhout files are tricky as a`\newwrite` allocation  gets saved in the format but the external filesystem handle isn't re-opened when the format is used so it can need some conditional code to fix up  the `\openout`  see `grep '=\\[wr]' mylatex.log 
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\beamer@verbatimfileout=\write4
\g__morewrites_iow=\write5
\g__morewrites_ior=\read3`  I may look later....